# GIMP: Why isn't my script-fu showing in the menus?

Tags: scheme, gimp

I've got a script-fu script that I want to use to modify an image in GIMP, but it's not showing in the menu I placed it in. It appears in the Procedure browser as I expected labelled "Temporary Procedure", something which I can't find any reference to in GIMP documentation. I tried refreshing scripts, re-opening GIMP and messing with where in the menus the script should be. My code definition is below. Any ideas?

```
(define (script-fu-<name>))

  (script-fu-register
    "script-fu-[name]"
    "[name]"
    "[description]"
    "[author]"
    "[copyright]"
    "[date]"
    "RGB*, GRAY*"
    SF-IMAGE "Image" 0
    SF-DRAWABLE "Layer" 0
  )
  (script-fu-menu-register "[name]" "<Image>/Image/[name]")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a script-fu expert, but I think that the `"[name]"` in `script-fu-menu-register` should be the name of the "atom" in `script-fu-register`, so that should be `"script-fu-[name]"`.